# Mist runs on one KDE machine no issue; identical version different machine - executable fails. Edit: Helpful Hint Added

Tags: mist

I've got a real brain-boggler here. Running mist no issue on one machine Ubuntu 14.04.4 KDE, identical version on another machine (cough) chromebook, chrooted, and the executable won't launch. I'd also note that it's not the hardware because I have mist running on other heavy chrooted distros, namely Unity and Mate. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ldd is a *beautiful* ***Beautiful*** command (checks binary dependencies and what's missing)

ldd Ethereum-Wallet

```
libgconf2.so.4 not found

**sudo apt-get install libgconf2.so.4**
```

Fetches from a google chrome server... Don't have chrome on machine Mist binaries fail. Do on the machine Mist works.

Low and behold Mist binaries now work with this dependency

Answer (score 0):

In a standard install of 19.10, `libgconf2.so.4` might not be available, so running `sudo apt-get install gconf2` is a recommended solution, which might solve your issue straight away.

In my case, I had to additionally run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to clean up a (previously?) broken install of `gconf2`.  I am not sure if this last step by itself might not have solved the problem immediately.